# Warning "Missing line break" in "data class" and "class" definitions (kotlin 1.4.M1)

Tags: android-studio, kotlin

I am not sure this have been forever in kotlin, but when using the newest version of Kotlin 1.4.M1 I found a (tiny) warning telling me: "Missing line break" in classes and data classes where the trailing paranthesis is on the same line as the last data definition.

Example

```
data class MyDataClass(
  var data: String,
  var data2: String)
```

causes "Missing line break" warning, but

```
data class MyDataClass(
   var data: String,
   var data2: String
)
```

does not cause any warning.

[My opinion, there is no difference between the two above]

I am (almost) sure this was not an issue in kotlin 1.3.70+

Using AS4.1C4.

Is this by design, or is this a "bug" in lint

RG

Comment: What IDE are you using? IntelliJ? please can you clear cache and restart

Comment: I am using Android Studio 4.1 Canary 4 with Kotlin 1.4.M1

Comment: Tried clearing cache and restart, but I think it relates to new functions in 1.4.x where you can have trailing comma after last definition. And where it isn't any, it will warn you by mistake that you should put the paranthesis on next line.